# How to disable ShoutBox in yetanotherforum?

Tags: yetanotherforum

I am using version 2.2.3 of yetanotherforum.

I need to disable the `Shoutbox` feature since it keeps making ajax requests every few milliseconds. I tried going through board settings under Admin, but could not find any setting for shoutbox.

How would I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shout box feature can be disabled in the host settings under  host > host settings > display tab